# Customizing asp:HyperLinkField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the standard GridView.

I have this part working so far.

```
    <asp:HyperLinkField ShowHeader="true" DataTextField="id" DataNavigateUrlFields="id"
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="edit.aspx?id={0}"
DataTextFormatString="Edit" />
```

However each page needs a 'number' and a 'userid' parameter.

I cannot figure out how to add these parameters to the above HyperLinkField.

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField ShowHeader="true" DataTextField="id"
   DataNavigateUrlFields="id"DataNavigateUrlFormatString="edit.aspx?id={0}
   &number=Request.QueryString["number"]&
   userid=Request.QueryString["userid"]" DataTextFormatString="Edit" />
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing to be able to add this custom URL to my HyperLinkField?

Comment: Use a templatefield instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [templatefield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx), something like (untested):

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <a href='<%# "edit.aspx?id="+Eval("id") + "&number=" +Request.QueryString["number"]+"&userid=" +Request.QueryString["userid"]  %>'>Edit</a>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: No problem. The HyperLinkField is really for binding properties from the object you are binding to the grid. The other way you could have done it would be to add the NavigateUrlField in the 'OnRowDataBound' event...but that's overkill for this